# Why can not subclass AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

In Apple API Reference, it says do not subclass AVPlayerViewController as above. I want to know why. I write a demo subclass AVPlayerViewController intentionally, it can play video normally. I can not find there is something is wrong.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do that makes you think you need to subclass it?

Comment: I want encapsulate avplayer in it so caller just past url parameters.

Comment: IIRC you can just pass a URL to it. I'm sure that's what I've done in the last app I wrote.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. The AVPlayer takes a URL. Why not create an extension to AVPlayerViewController with a function that takes a URL and initialises an AVPlayer and AVPlayerVieaController and returns the controller?

Comment: I know this feature can be implemented in that way. I just want to know why can not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Apple do not explain why.

Comment: Try it. Let us know. Make sure you test everything though as you may miss something and think it's working fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although AVPlayerViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, instances of it cannot be presented using presentViewController

more detail:
[Delivering Intuitive Media Playback with AVKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/503/)